# Navigation to multiple pages using React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

MY app component

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="mb-5">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/form" element={<Form />} />
                    <Route path="/productsList/:cate" element={<ProductsList />} />
                    <Route path="/singleproduct/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
                    <Route path="/filters" element={<MobileFilters />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My fitersection component

```
<div className="md:hidden ">
                <div
                    className=" text-xl flex items-center gap-4 w-44"
                    onClick={() => navigate("/mobilefilters")}
                >
                    Filters
                    <BsFilterCircleFill />
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

My MobileFilters component

```
const MobileFilters = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <>
            <div className="bg-orange-400 h-8 flex items-center ">
                <button className="ml-2" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
                    <BsArrowLeft className="text-2xl" />
                </button>
            </div>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
                <div className="col-span-2 bg-slate-300 h-screen flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-lg ">
                    <NavLink to="/brand">Brand</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/rating">Rating</NavLink>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-4 ">
                    <FilterPage />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

I tried to create a seperate FilterPage component which will render the multiple pages like below

```
const FilterPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/brand" element={<Brand />} />
                <Route path="/rating" element={<Rating />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
};
```

and Brand Component

```
const Brand = () => {
    return <div>Brand</div>;
};
```

and Rating component

```
const Rating = () => {
    return <div>Rating</div>;
};
```

But as soon as clicks on Brand in MobileFilters Component is shows no routes matched. but when I am linking these pages in app component directly they are rendering. I am building a filter section like flipkart on mobile but am stuck on this part
I am providing the img also.
[image]
This is the mobilefilters component in which i wants is that when I click on brand, it should show brand filters. So any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no route for `/brand` in your routes. What are you expecting to be rendered here?

Comment: I have added route for /brand in FilterPage component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

You are navigating to `"/mobilefilters"` which isn't a path you are rendering a route for. I'll assume you meant for the `"/filters"` route to be `"/mobilefilters"` since it does appear the `MobileFilters` component is rendered since you can see the links to "Brand" and "Rating".

The issue is that `MobileFilters` is rendering `FilterPage` which is rendering ***descendent routes*** but the parent route `"/mobilefilters"` isn't allowing for the matching and rendering of descendent routes.

## Solution

To resolve, append the `"*"` wildcard matcher to the parent route to allow descendent routes to be matched and rendered.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/form" element={<Form />} />
    <Route path="/productsList/:cate" element={<ProductsList />} />
    <Route path="/singleproduct/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
    <Route
      path="/mobilefilters/*" // <-- allow descendent route matching
      element={<MobileFilters />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`MobileFilters` will need to correctly link to the descendent routes which are built/rendered relative to the parent route path.

```
const MobileFilters = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-orange-400 h-8 flex items-center ">
        <button className="ml-2" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
          <BsArrowLeft className="text-2xl" />
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
        <div className="col-span-2 bg-slate-300 h-screen flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-lg ">
          <NavLink to="brand">Brand</NavLink>   // <-- relative link
          <NavLink to="rating">Rating</NavLink> // <-- relative link
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 ">
          <FilterPage />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

### Alternative

Alternatively you could convert `MobileFilters` into a layout route component where it renders an `Outlet` instead of `FilterPage`, and move the routes `FilterPage` was rendering to now be ***nested*** routes.

```
const MobileFilters = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-orange-400 h-8 flex items-center ">
        <button className="ml-2" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
          <BsArrowLeft className="text-2xl" />
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
        <div className="col-span-2 bg-slate-300 h-screen flex flex-col gap-y-2 text-lg ">
          <NavLink to="/brand">Brand</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/rating">Rating</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 ">
          <Oulet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/form" element={<Form />} />
    <Route path="/productsList/:cate" element={<ProductsList />} />
    <Route path="/singleproduct/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
    <Route path="/mobilefilters" element={<MobileFilters />}>
      <Route path="brand" element={<Brand />} />   // <-- rendered into Outlet
      <Route path="rating" element={<Rating />} /> // <-- rendered into Outlet
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I personally find alternative approach of using Outlet good because it is mostly used for nested routing and in my case it is nested routing. I once again appreciate your help